# How to get the response from the second redirect in rest assured?

Tags: redirect, http-redirect, rest-assured, response.redirect

I am using rest assured and I am trying to get a response from a redirect, so I have a request which is without an SSL certificate i.e the domain is http and the server automatically does a 301(which is the redirect) to a https domain(which is the 200). What I want to do is to get the response from the https domain i.e from the 200 status code. Don't know why but I get a org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException when using this code:

```
protected RequestSpecification specRedirect() {
        RestAssuredConfig restAssuredConfig = RestAssuredConfig.config()
                .redirect(redirectConfig().followRedirects(true).and().maxRedirects(1))
                .objectMapperConfig(new ObjectMapperConfig().jackson2ObjectMapperFactory(
                        (aClass, s) -> new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
                ));
        RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
        restAssuredConfig = restAssuredConfig.httpClient(httpClientConfig().setParam(PARAMETER_NAME, TIMEOUT_VALUE));
        RequestSpecification spec = new TestSpecificationImpl(
                new RequestSpecBuilder()
                        .setConfig(restAssuredConfig)
                        .setBaseUri(this.baseURI)
                        .setBasePath(this.basePath)
                        .addFilters(this.filters)
                        .addHeaders(this.headers)
                        .build(),
                new ResponseSpecBuilder()
                        .build()
        ).getRequestSpecification();

        if (cookies != null && useCookies) {
            spec.cookies(cookies);
        }
        return spec;
    }
```

And I call this method in the test like this:

```
public Response getUrl(Cookie cookie, Cookie cookie, String domain, String string, String string, String string) {
        return specRedirect()
                .cookie(cookie)
                .cookie(cookie)
                .get(domain + "/string/string/string" + string + "?string=" + string + "&string=" + string + string);
    }
```

Any help? :)

Comment: "getUrl(Cookie cookie, Cookie cookie, String domain, String string, String string, String string)", is this really your code?

Comment: Not really, just did that in order to post the question and not use the actual name of the cookies :)

Comment: So, you expect someone else to find an error in something that looks like your code?  Good luck!  Otherwise, give us something we can at least try.

Comment: What difference does it make to you if I write the actual name of the cookie or not?

Comment: If you've got two or more parameters with the same name, no way your code is going to work.  If you don't provide the means to reproduce your problem, it will be hard to solve it.  As you can see, the past 9 hours the solutions are not exactly pouring in.

Comment: BTW, don't you need to specify a protocol with `RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation()` ?